# Getting error ExecuteReader: CommandText when running comments in query

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an error when running a basic query and I cannot understand why.

It seems to be caused when comments are run by themselves.

Below are two query examples. The first gives no error, the second does.

Query 1:

```
print 'test'

-- test
```

Result 1:

> ```
> test
> ```

Query 2:

```
print 'test'
go
-- test
```

Result 2:

> ```
> test
> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized
> ```

My question is, why are comments returning this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: What are you running these in? `GO` isn't a Transact-SQL command, it's an IDE command recognised in IDE's like SSMS, Azure Data Studio, and command lines like `sqlcmd`.

Comment: I'm running in SSMS. I used GO to separate the statements.

Comment: I feel like there's something you're not telling us then. That 2nd query doesn't generate an error in SSMS 18.

Comment: And it shouldn't generate an error, not even in 17. Hence my confusion. If I open a new query, type "-- test", or any other commented text, I will get the same error. It did not do this before, so I cannot understand why it is happening now.

I imagine something is wrong with the setup somehow but I cannot imagine what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what causing the problem.

Issue was being caused because I was connected using "Additional Connection Parameters"

```
Column Encryption Setting = Enabled
```

This was also causing strange errors like repeated print messages.

When I removed this setting everything went back to normal.